# Android Imageview distorted when viewing on landscape large devices

Tags: android, xml, imageview, fill-parent

I am currently trying to show an image using imageview, this image just has the certain height but it should fill the entire width of the screen. On portrait mode it and landscape mode on a mobile phone(Samsung galaxy note 2) it shows just fine but when I tried it on a tablet(Samsung galaxy tab), the portrait mode still looks great But in landscape mode what happens is that the image looks distorted, the image covers the entire width but the height seems to be off.

I did check it on the graphical layout but it looks ok.

this is my imageView:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/footersuperlong" />
```

Did I do something that makes it distorted?How can I make the image correctly display on the landscape view of a tablet?

Comment: Try using a fixed `layout_height`?

Comment: @ChillyChan tried it still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the tab's width will be more compared to mobile phone.
So the image get scaled up to match the width.

You should use different image for different screens. Put different images in different drawable folder like hdpi,mdpi,xhdpi, If the images are stretchable use nine patch images.

Define different layout for tablet sized screen.

checkout [multiscreen support](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) and [screen_sizes](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html) for more info

Comment: I've done a multi layout for this but what I did was that my image is a high resolution one (1280 x 85). When I look at it at the different layouts, its all ok, but when I load it the device it becomes enlarged and pixelated.

Comment: How are you looking in different layouts ?

Comment: in graphical view, whenever I select the dimensions of the tablet, it goes to the large-layout, and when I try to rotate it there it goes to the landscape layout with the image being just fine. I'm using relativeLayout for all of my layouts. I do however edit them using the xml file itself.